# Async function that calls itself

Tags: javascript, async-await

Is it a good idea to make a async function call itself, when you have a list of things that need to be done in order?

Example:

```
async continueWork(){

   if(!this.list.length)
     return;

   var next = this.list.shift();

   // do things with next

   await this.continueWork();
}
```

What happens if the list is very large? Can it cause problems?

Comment: That... doesn't make a lot of sense. If the function calls itself, then you've just modelled normal, synchronous code calling using async/await keywords. What are you _actually_ trying to do?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans He left out the asynchronous stuff in "do things with next". Imagine that it performs an AJAX call in there.

Comment: literally doesn't matter. For the occasional async operation (not call), need to use to use the async/await syntactic sugar, just directly use a promise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this can cause problems. Each `continueWork` call is put onto the call stack, on top of the last `continueWork`, which can result in an overflow:

```js
let i = 0;
async function continueWork() {
  i++;
  if (i < 1e5) {
    await continueWork();
  }
}

continueWork()
  .then(() => console.log('ok'))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('err');
    console.log(err.stack);
  });
```

You can fix it by `await`ing something inside `continueWork` before it recursively calls itself, so that the call stack doesn't pile up:

```js
let i = 0;
async function continueWork() {
  i++;
  await Promise.resolve();
  if (i < 1e5) {
    await continueWork();
  }
}

continueWork()
  .then(() => console.log('ok'))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('err');
    console.log(err.stack);
  });
```

The important thing is to ensure that there aren't a large number of *synchronous* function calls before the call stack empties. `await` (or `.then`) ensures that what follows the `await`, or the `.then` callback, executes in a microtask (which will occur only after the call stack is clear).

Comment: I suspect that the "do something" that he didn't show includes awaiting something asynchronous.

Comment: yes, do thing with next is more await calls of other functions. so its ok then :)

Comment: `this.continueWork()` looks very odd

Comment: @marzelin Ha, didn't even notice that, it simply happened to work because it was in sloppy mode on the top level

Answer (score 0):

why not use the good old while?

```
async continueWork(){
    while(this.list.length){
       let next = this.list.shift()
       await do_things_with_next(next)
    }
}
```